# Use HTML daterange form data to select for a date range in MySQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, datepicker

Thank you for viewing this question. I have implemented a jquery/html datepicker form that allows users to select a start date and an end date. The HTML for this form is:

```
        <form id="MyForm">
            <input type="text" class = "datepicker" name = "StartDate" id="StartDate" placeholder = "Start Date" style = "width : 85px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 1mm;"/>
            <br />
            <input type="text" class = "datepicker" name = "EndDate" id="EndDate" placeholder = "End Date" style = "width : 85px; margin-left: 10px;"/>
            <br />
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Go" style = "font-weight: bold; margin-left: 10px;"/>
        </form>
```

The jquery is pretty simple and stores the inputted dates in the same format as the format of the dates in the MySQL table I am querying from.

I would like to create a system in this web page that allows users to dynamically alter the results displayed in terms of the selected date range. Ideally, I would like to do this in a dynamic fashion using AJAX. Bear in mind that this page is already receiving a REQUEST in terms of a separate field's (project) identity. What I mean by this is that a page's URL is going to be something like ~~~~.php?project=LOW003, where LOW003 is a session variable $project. The date range form should alter the query below to one that selects in terms of the inputted date range:

```
      SELECT project, participant, reel, machine, qc_gsr, qc_hr, qc_acz, qc_bre 
          FROM rtcdb.session 
          WHERE site = 'ORL001';
```

I would like to turn this query, based on the date-range form inputs, to something like:

```
     SELECT project, participant, reel, machine, qc_gsr, qc_hr, qc_acz, qc_bre 
         FROM rtcdb.session 
         WHERE download_date >= '$start_date' 
         AND download_date <= '$end_date';
```

To sum it up, I would like to use AJAX and PHP to get input vars from an HTML form stored in the format yy-mm-dd to then alter all of my MySQL queries to select in terms of a date range. Thanks for your help!

Comment: WARNING: `and stores the inputted dates in the same format as the format of the dates in the MySQL table` but not if I manually type it!

Comment: looks like you heading in the right direction. `if(isset($_REQUEST['start_date'])) { // check valid and add to SQL }` and the same for `end date`, so you can do FROM, UP UNTIL and BETWEEN in one go

Comment: There's no way for you to manually type it since users can only select the date from a pop-up calendar. Check out JQuery UI datepicker bud

Comment: Ok, but how do I get to that point in the first place?

Comment: did and done and manually typed `34545454/454///3453453452`

Comment: True! lol, but this isn't a commercial application. Its being used in an enterprise setting. And if I wanted to I am sure I could modify the JQ to prevent a user from typing in nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm building an SQL for use by depreciated mysql_* functions to show meaning only:

```
$where=array();
if( (isset($_REQUEST['site'])) && (!empty($_REQUEST['site'])) )
{
    $where[]="site='".mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_REQUEST['site']))."'";
}
if( (isset($_REQUEST['start_date'])) && (!empty($_REQUEST['start_date'])) )
{
    $where[]="download_date>='".mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_REQUEST['start_date']))."'";
}
if( (isset($_REQUEST['end_date'])) && (!empty($_REQUEST['end_date'])) )
{
    $where[]="download_date<='".mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_REQUEST['end_date']))."'";
}

$sql="SELECT project, participant, reel, machine, qc_gsr, qc_hr, qc_acz, qc_bre 
FROM rtcdb.session";
if(sizeof($where)>0)
{
    $sql.=" WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $where);
}

echo $sql;
```

You can prepare the statement too, but it was quicker for me to explain this way.
No Validation carried out as per comments